# Unable to play mp3 file in android streaming from JAVA Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, mp3

server side audio file Audio format is

```
new AudioFormat(
                  AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                  44100,
                  16,
                  baseFormat.getChannels(),
                  baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                  baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                  false);
```

the following is my java code of server reading mp3 file and sending to android client

```
final int READ_THRESHOLD = 2147483647;
                  int framesReaded = READ_THRESHOLD;
                  Header header;
                  for(; framesReaded-- > 0 && (header = bitstream.readFrame()) != null;) {
                      SampleBuffer sampleBuffer = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(header, bitstream);
                      short[] buffer = sampleBuffer.getBuffer();
                      DataOutputStream oos=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                      for(short ss:buffer) {
                          oos.writeShort(ss);
                      }
                      bitstream.closeFrame();
                      sentCount++;                    
                      //.SendToAll(_buffer, 0, _buffer.length);
                      //oos.close();
                      if(sentCount >=100) {
                          sentCount=0;
                          System.out.println("Connect Recooneted");
                          socket.close();

                          startConnect();

                      }
                  }
```

Following is my android code

```
static final int frequency = 44100;
    static final int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
    static final int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

playBufSize=AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, playBufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.setVolume(10);
  int readCount = _streamIn.read(data, 0, data.length);
                            if (readCount > 0) {

                           audioTrack.write(data, 0, data.length);

                        }
```

but i am unable to get song play in android. Can any one help me out.

Comment: This question needs a lot more information. Have you done any debugging? Have you verified the audio is decoded correctly on the server? Have you verified the client is receiving it correctly? Where is your call to `audioTrack.play()`?

Comment: yah, when i use same android code but i used Server android mic as android so that i got voice from android. when when i used java code with mp3 file to play its not playing.